# Haskell functions in case statements

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I've been trying for a few days to code a dictionary in Haskell, and I have a problem with case structure that i can't solve. Every time I try to compile this piece of code, i get this error:

```
Dictionary.hs:24:130: error: Parse error in pattern: insertChild

   |
24 |    then case getNodeType x of (1-> insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining xs)
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand if I simply cannot use functions in Haskell or what is the problem exactly. I am new to Haskell.

The entire piece of code is this:

```
insertChild :: Char -> [Char] -> [Dictionary] -> [Dictionary] --ED
insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining [] = if (length wordRemaining) == 0 --Si no me quedan letras 
                                               then (LETTERNODE currentLetter [WORDNODE]):[]--Añado el WORDNODE porque ya terminé la palabra
                                               else (LETTERNODE currentLetter (insertChild (head wordRemaining) (tail wordRemaining) [])):[]--Añado otro nodo con la letra y sigo con la recursión
insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining (x:xs) = if (length wordRemaining) == 0 --Si no me quedan letras
                                                 then case getNodeType x of (1-> insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining xs)
                                                                            (0-> caseInsertChild1 currentLetter wordRemaining (x:xs))
                                                 else case getNodeType x of 1-> (insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining xs)
                                                                            0-> (caseInsertChild2 currentLetter wordRemaining (x:xs))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Parse error" is GHC-speak for "*syntax* error".

Comment: You should be using curly brackets in the `case`, not round brackets.

Comment: @PaulJohnson and semicolons. :) I'm being serious; I don't understand the value of whitespace--brittleness. explicit separators do not preclude sensible indentation, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write this with parentheses:

```
case something of
  (pattern -> expression)
  (pattern -> expression)
```

but only without:

```
case something of
  pattern -> expression
  pattern -> expression
```

This would also be correct

```
case something of
  pattern -> (expression)
  pattern -> (expression)
```

but the above parentheses are redundant, so it's better to omit them.

Also, I would recommend you replace the inefficient `length ... == 0`, and the partial `head`, `tail` uses with proper pattern matching. It's simpler, safer, and more efficient.

```
insertChild currentLetter []     []     = ...
insertChild currentLetter (w:ws) []     = ...
insertChild currentLetter []     []     = ...
insertChild currentLetter (w:ws) (x:xs) = ...
```

Comment: But if I don't use the parentheses I get this error:

Unexpected case expression in function application:
        case getNodeType x of {
          1 -> insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining xs }
    You could write it with parentheses
    Or perhaps you meant to enable BlockArguments?
   |
24 |                                                                                                  then case getNodeType x of 1 -> insertChild currentLetter wordRemaining xs
   |

Comment: @Federino You might have some indentation issues. Ensure that every branch of the case in indented at the same level, with the same amount of spaces (not TAB characters).